# How to know programmatically the actual modified component?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

In J2ME there is the interface `ItemStateListener` which can detect exactly the item which is being `changed`. Is there a similar way in LWUIT ? I tried using the `DataChangedListener` interface but it gives the character position within the TextField , or -1 , for the `index` argument ! So ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially set the `boolean` value to false and add the listener for the components then if any event occurs on that components, set the boolean value to true. Use the `addDataChangeListener`(It only for `TextField`) or `addActionListener` for the components. On `addDataChangeListener` returns two index values. Initially returns -1 and then returns current text position of the `TextField`. AFAIK On `TextField`, they set the default index value is -1 for `fireDataChanged` on `setText` method. That is why it will returns -1 initially.